# Japanese コ上 meaning in English

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

I've perused many sites and have found "コ上," but if I hit translate, I get "co-on," a term I am not familiar with. Is this a Japanese term with no English equivalent?

I'm attempting to read a manga and this phrase pops up twice and has me completely baffled. Below are the contexts in which I found them. Any help would be much appreciated.

> オレらより１**コ上**なんだけど
>   海外行ってる間の
>   単位取得で

and

> １**コ上**の先輩に聞いたんだけど
>   留学先で仲間と会社設立して
>   すんごい儲けたんだって

Comment: I bet the reason you're getting "co-on" is that the translation software tokenizes it into コ, which it treats a loanword from English "co" (like [the prefix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-#English), maybe?), plus 上, which can, in some contexts, mean "on" (机の上の本 = "the book _on_ the desk"). Given that コ上 isn't a lexical item in Japanese, one can scarcely expect the translation software to do much better.

Comment: I don't recommend using translation software to learn Japanese.  It'll work okay when you're lucky, but it'll just confuse you when you're not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason you aren't finding it is that you're parsing wrong.

You should split it as 1コ and then 上. And for this コ, you can think of it as the kanji [個]{こ}, which is one of the most generic counter words in Japanese. See [the Wikipedia article on Japanese counter word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word) and [ウィキペディア「日本語の助数詞」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E6%95%B0%E8%A9%9E#.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E8.AA.9E.E3.81.AE.E5.8A.A9.E6.95.B0.E8.A9.9E).

１個上 in this case means 1 level above.

So:

> オレらより１コ上なんだけど

= he's one [year/grade] above us but ...

> １コ上の先輩に聞いたんだけど ...

= I heard it from the *sempai* one year above us but ...

---

As per the comment, this can only be used for comparatives, like 1個上, 2コ下, ...

If you want to say the year directly, you would say 一年生, 二年生

Comment: It is probably worth noting that コ(個) is used only for difference between ages/grades. 「私は 1年生で、彼は2コ上の 3年生」 is correct but 「私は1コ生」 is wrong.

Comment: What nuance is imbued by using コ in place of 個? I don't believe it's emphasis (like in オレら).

Comment: @jogloran I'd guess it's just a stylistic choice. I've seen コ used in place of 個 before in manga and such. Anyway, I've never seen １コ上 to refer to age. It's always been 1つ上