# Meaning of 一段階ショック

Tags: meaning

I'm not quite sure how to understand what is being said in bold below. The first part is him thinking that he could forgive her a little since she is more beautiful than the ugly girls that have hated him. He then says however, it might actually be ....

> 頭のどこかで「今まで俺を嫌ってきたブス子さんたちより、そこそこ美人な分少し許せる」と思っていたのだが、**逆に一段階ショックかもしれない**

Unfortunately 一段階ショック doesn't seem to be a common phrase when googling it, but the hits suggest that it is to do with the "first step/stage" of something. Most of examples I saw on google were describing the first stage of "pet loss" as shock.

Would anyone be able to help me understand what he means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe or not, this is a comparative expression.

> 逆に一段階ショックかもしれない
> *It's actually one notch more shocking/hurting*

Japanese does not have a piece of grammar that corresponds to the comparative, but it does have several constructions to do its jobs. ショック is a na-adjective in Japanese that means mostly the same as in English: "to be (emotionally) shocked", and the [numeral] + [counter] + [adjective] pattern implicitly conveys the meaning "[numeral] more [adjective]".

> 一回り大きい *one size bigger*
> 二つ年上（だ） *two years older* ([a related post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28141/7810))
> 三人少ない *three fewer people* (= outnumbered by three)

In many cases, you'll see a noun phrase with ～より (meaning "than") somewhere before the expression, which should make it easier to understand. However, you will also see it alone if that element is left out.

**Bonus**: I think 許せる in this passage is better understood as "acceptable" rather than "forgivable".

Comment: Sorry for asking this so late after, but what usage does 分 fall under here? The grammar of it strikes me as odd.

Comment: @user26484 Does this answer you? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61583/7810

Comment: Yes. So it more-or-less means "Her fairly charming qualities (そこそこ美人な分) makes her that much more agreeable" ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the plot, but I'd read "makes me less offended".